# How do I fix python sockets that aren't listening/accepting information?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, ubuntu

I have two ubuntu machines, a server and a client. I am trying to get my client to send information to the server, have the server handle the info and respond with a message. My code is below. Right now, the "Message received" will print on the server side, but the "Message accepted" will not, which makes me think that the "conn, addr s.accept()" is the problematic line. Any help on discovering why the code isn't working would be helpful.

server.py

```
import socket
serverprivateIP = '172.31.89.96'
port = 54352

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(("",port))
    s.listen()
    print("Message received")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Message accepted")
    with conn:
            while True:
                    data = conn.recv(8192)
                    if not data:
                            break
                    text = data.decode()
                    lines = 0
                    words = 0
                    characters = 0
                    for line in text:
                            line = line.strip("\n")
                            word = line.split()
                            lines += 1
                            words += len(word)
                            characters += len(line)
                    text.close()
                    toReturn = lines + " " + words + " " + characters + " "
                    conn.send(toReturn)
```

client.py

```
import socket
import os

serverIP = "3.89.222.117"
port = 54352

MAXBUFFER = 8192

file = "file.txt"

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((serverIP,port))
    with open(file,"rb") as filereader:
            content = filereader.read(MAXBUFFER)
            s.send(content)
            results = s.recv(1024)
            print(results.decode())
socket.close()
```

Comment: What is `next`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `next` as a variable name, it's a built-in function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: `serverIP` isn't the same as `serverprivateIP`. If the server is behind a router, do you have port forwarding configured? And is the port allowed through the firewall?

Comment: `text.close()` ? `text` is a string, not a file or connection.

Comment: I suggest you first get the basics working by testing it locally, then worry about connecting between different machines.